# Get bibtex entries from metadata of PDF files

Tags: bash, pdf, tex

When I have to write a report or an article, I usually have my bibliography as PDFs in a specific folder, so I wrote this script to automate the generation of bibtex entries.

It works so far, but I'd like to have suggestions about what I could improve

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

FOLDER=$1
BIBTEX_FILE=$2

cd $FOLDER
for f in *; do
    echo "Examining $f"
    TITLE=`pdfinfo $f | grep Title | cut -c17-`

    echo "Title found in PDF metadata is : $TITLE"

    case "$TITLE" in
        doi*)
            echo "This is a DOI, nice!"
            DOI=`echo $TITLE | cut -c5-`;;
        *)
            case "$TITLE" in
                "untitled")
                    echo "Let's see what we can find in the text"
                    DOI=`pdftotext $f /tmp/pdf | cat /tmp/pdf | grep -i 'doi\|Digital Object Identifier' | awk 'NF>1{print $NF}'`;;
                *)
                    echo "Let's find a DOI from this title"
                    TITLE=`echo $TITLE | sed 's/ /%20/g'`
                    URL="http://api.crossref.org/works?query=$TITLE&rows=1"
                    DOI=`curl -s $URL | jq '.message.items[].DOI' | sed 's/"//g'`;;
            esac
    esac

    echo "The DOI is $DOI"
    echo "----------------------------------"
    URL="http://api.crossref.org/works/$DOI/transform/application/x-bibtex"
    curl -s $URL >> $BIBTEX_FILE
    echo >> $BIBTEX_FILE
    echo >> $BIBTEX_FILE
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Always double-quote variables if they might contain spaces

These commands will fail if the variables contain spaces:

> ```
> cd $FOLDER
>
> # ...
>
> echo >> $BIBTEX_FILE
> ```

Even if you never intend to use your script with paths containing spaces,
it's good to make it a habit to double-quote variables that might contain spaces:

```
cd "$FOLDER"

# ...

echo >> "$BIBTEX_FILE"
```

#### Error checking

What will happen if this command fails?

> ```
> cd $FOLDER
> ```

If this fails, the program will happily continue,
download a likely invalid url with `curl`,
and create a bogus `$BIBTEX_FILE`,
essentially putting garbage in the current directory.

Look for possible points of failure where the program should abort.
If something goes wrong with this `cd` command you definitely don't want execution to continue.
Here's a simple way to abort:

```
cd "$FOLDER" || exit 1
```

Here's a more user-friendly way:

```
if ! cd "$FOLDER"; then
    echo "error: could not cd into $FOLDER"
    exit 1
fi
```

#### Use the modern `$(...)` instead of the obsolete `` `...` ``

For example:

```
TITLE=$(pdfinfo "$f" | grep Title | cut -c17-)
```

Notice that I double-quoted `$f`, as it should be.

#### Bogus pipeline

This is strange:

> ```
> pdftotext $f /tmp/pdf | cat /tmp/pdf | ...
> ```

In a pipeline, usually the output of one command is passed as input to the next through `stdout` and `stdin` file handles. That's not what happens here, data is passed through a file. This is unusual and confusing.
Also confusing is to name a text file `/tmp/pdf`.

You don't need a temporary file here,
`pdftotext` can produce output on `stdout`,
and then you don't need `cat` either:

```
pdftotext $f - | ...
```

#### Removing double-quotes from the output of `jq`

Instead of this:

> ```
> curl -s $URL | jq '.message.items[].DOI' | sed 's/"//g'
> ```

You can remove the double-quotes by using the `--raw-output` flag:

```
curl -s "$URL" | jq -r '.message.items[].DOI'
```

`-r` is a shortcut for `--raw-output`.
Notice also, once again, that I added the necessary double-quotes around `$URL`.

#### Redirecting multiple statements

This kind of repetition quickly becomes annoying:

> ```
> curl -s $URL >> $BIBTEX_FILE
> echo >> $BIBTEX_FILE
> echo >> $BIBTEX_FILE
> ```

You can dispense with that using grouping:

```
{
    curl -s "$URL"
    echo
    echo
} >> "$BIBTEX_FILE"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. So many ways to do one thing in bash scripts, and pretty difficult to figure out the *right* way. I know the is against the rules but... thank you.